# how do you say 'super rad day!' in japanese?

Tags: grammar, meaning

i'm working on a logo for a customer's brand, and she wrote out スーパーラッドデー！
but, couldn't it also be-
スーパーラッドデイ！?

which one should i use? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

*Hi, Salem!*

> Day can be both デイ or デー. Both have the same pronunciation as the
>   vowel sound e+i is often seen as a extension of the first sound. Take
>   for example せんせい, it is pronounced as せんせー, but ー is not used as it is only used with katakana. Other examples are
>   ゲーム、メール,etc.

---

Have a look yourself: [HiNative - Question](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/4192885), [Reference Database for Both](https://crd.ndl.go.jp/reference/modules/d3ndlcrdentry/index.php?page=ref_view&id=1000272112),　[デイ usage](https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=%E3%83%87%E3%82%A4&from=jpn&to=eng),　[デー usage](https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC&from=jpn&to=eng).

Furthermore, there is a trend observed in [NHK Research (page 94)](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/research/kotoba/pdf/20160501_2.pdf) indicating that デイ is *often* used in the beggining and デー at the end of a word.
I would say スーパーラッドデー, reasoning from the clues of all the sources above and that it was your customer who sent it to you. Hope this helps!